# Laravel - Install package via composer and access it in controller

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have an laravel application and I need to install this package [`lunar-calendar`](https://github.com/yzha5/lunar-calendar)

I install it and the package shows in vendor folder:
[image]

The package documentation tells to required the package like this:

```
use yzha5\LunarCalendar;
```

I put this way but also try this in controller:

```
use App\yzha5\LunarCalendar;
```

but returns not found.

I also run the command to publish vendor but doesn't work.

How can I use this package?

Comment: returns me not found @fubar

Answer (score 0):

The package doesn't contain a service provider, so publish vendor will accomplish nothing really.

```
use yzha5\LunarCalendar; 
\\ will not work because it isn't registered in your service provider that this alias equals the package path

use App\yzha5\LunarCalendar; 
\\ will not work because there isn't a folder in app directory named yzha5.
```

Since it's just two classes and not exactly a decently build package, I'd just fetch those two files into a directory at your choosing, change the namespace and call them.

Comment: I try this but don't work... How can I call this right?
provider ->  yzha5\LunarCalendar::class,
aliases -> 'LunarCalendar' => yzha5\LunarCalendar::class,
@abr

Comment: It won't work because that class is not a service provider class, I've checked the 'chinese package' that you placed above, the best solution will be to just copypaste those files into a directory of your choosing. Here is an example of a well-made package:   https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitHub